# Modelling a decreasing growth rate - I want to calculate a growth model in discrete time such that my client base grows from 5 to 10000 in 8 years?

Tags: finance, modeling, exponential, mathematical-expressions

I am looking at a financial model such that at time=0 the number of clients I have is 5. If I consider discrete time such that the number of clients at time t is equal to:

y(t) = y<sub>0</sub> * ∏ <sup>t-1</sup><sub>0</sub>  (1 + r(i))

I want to know if each period is a month and in 8 years I have 10000 clients (so 96 months total discrete periods) where the growth rate r(i) decreases each month over the 8 years; what formula for r(i) can I use to achieve this or what formula can be used to help me calculate this please based on a changing inital growth rate?

Comment: it is not 0^(t-1) it is the multiplicative sum of 1+r(i) for i from 0 to t-1. I will adjust to make this clearer

Comment: This question is probably better suited for the [Mathematics](https://math.stackexchange.com/) Stack Exchange.